# C++ std::atomic vs. Boost atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

In my application, I have an int and a bool variable, which are accessed (multiple write/read) by multiple threads. Currently, I am using two mutexes, one for int and one for bool to protect those variables.

I heard about using atomic variables and operators to write lock-free multi-thread program. My questions are

1. What's the definition of atomic variables and operators?
2. What's the main difference between **std::atomic** and
   **boost/atomic.hpp**? Which one is more standard or popular?
3. Are these libraries platform-dependent? I am using gnu gcc 4.6 on
   Linux at the moment, but ideally it shall be cross-platform. I heard that the definition of "atomic" actually depends on the hardware as well. Can anyone explain that as well?
4. What's the best way to share a bool variable among multiple threads? I would prefer not to use the "**volatile**" keyword.

Are these code thread-safe?

```
double double_m; // double_m is only accessed by current thread.
std::atomic<bool> atomic_bool_x;
atomic_bool_x = true && (double_m > 12.5);

int int_n; // int_n is only accessed by current thread.
std::atomic<int> atomic_int_x;
std::atomic<int> atomic_int_y;
atomic_int_y = atomic_int_x * int_n;
```

Comment: That's a lot of questions to be asking all at once. Also, are you asking if the C++ standard library is... standard? And platform-dependent?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not an expert or anything, but here's what I know:

1. `std::atomic` simply says that calling `load` and `store` (and a few other operations) concurrently is well-defined. An atomic operation is indivisible - nothing can happen 'in-between'.
2. I assume `std::atomic` is based off of `boost::atomic`. If you can, use `std`, otherwise use `boost`.
3. They are both portable, with the `std` being completely so, however your compiler will need to support C++11
4. Likely `std::atomic_bool`. You should not need to use volatile.

Also, I believe `load`/`store` differs from `operator=`/`operator T` <s>only `load`/`store` are atomic</s>.

Nevermind. I checked the standard and it appears that the operators are defined in terms of `load`/`store`/etc, however they may return different things.

Further reading:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic
- C++11 Standard
- C++ Concurrency in Action

Comment: Actually `Boost.Atomic` is based on the standard atomic library.

Comment: Also, load and store do more than just be indivisible. They also define memory ordering requirements. Only if you specify memory_order_relaxed are they merely indivisible.

Answer (score 7):

Volatile is orthogonal to what you use to implement atomics. In C++ it tells the compiler that certain it is not safe to perform optimizations with that variable. Herb Sutters lays it out:

> To safely write lock-free code that communicates between threads without using locks, prefer to use ordered atomic variables: Java/.NET volatile, C++0x atomic, and C-compatible atomic_T.
>
> To safely communicate with special hardware or other memory that has unusual semantics, use unoptimizable variables: ISO C/C++ volatile. Remember that reads and writes of these variables are not necessarily atomic, however.
>
> Finally, to express a variable that both has unusual semantics and has any or all of the atomicity and/or ordering guarantees needed for lock-free coding, only the ISO C++0x draft Standard provides a direct way to spell it: volatile atomic.

(from http://drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=212701484&siteSectionName=parallel)

Answer (score 2):

1. See *[std::atomic class template](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/atomic/atomic.html)*
2. `std::atomic` is standard since C++11, and the Boost stuff is older. But since it is standard now, I would prefer `std::atomic`.
3. ?? You can use `std::atomic` with each C++11 compiler on each platform you want.
4. Without any further information...

   std::atomic;

Answer (score 1):

I believe `std::atomic` (C++11) and `boost.atomic` are equivalent. If `std::atomic` is not supported by your compiler yet, use `boost::atomic`.