# C++ 11 Thread vs Boost Thread is there any difference?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using the C++11 multithreading classes versus the ones found in Boost? I will only be using Linux so I do not require portability. Is there a lack of features in one of the libraries? Any known limitations? Better syntax?

Comment: Yes, there are also these: 1) [What to prefer, std::thread or boost::thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365196/what-to-prefer-stdthread-or-boost-threads), 2) [std::atomic vs boost:atomic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551750/c-stdatomic-v-s-boost-atomic) and 3) [Why the C++ Standard Committee rejected boost::shared_mutex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659295/why-c0x-standard-committee-rejected-boostshared-mutex)

Comment: @itwasntpete Actually, a lot of things changed in Boost.Thread in the past 2 years.

Answer (score 4):

Standard threads have the advantage of being standardised, therefore portable to any compliant implementation.

The Boost thread library is more or less identical; the standard library was based on that library, and there has been an effort to make Boost a conformant implementation of the standard. It has a few extensions which might be useful, including:

- `join` with timeout
- thread interruption
- thread groups
- extra lock types

Answer (score 1):

In general, boost classes are only wrappers around functions/objects that exist in given OS. Their main advantage is that boost contains versions written for most operating systems, hence the wrapper provides portability the original functions/objects sometimes do not.

If there is nothing else your need from boost I would strongly suggest using standard C++11 threads.

Reasons:

- boost will not provide more than the system allows for
- your code will not have any wrapper overhead (however small it may be)
- boost support for c++11 threads is a new feature and I would fear that it could introduce some errors in the boosts' implementation
- you will not have to rely on boost libraries and will save yourself time compiling and linking them, etc.
- you will not have to update boost, because you will not be using it

Of course, boost has some pros also:

- many people know boost and the code will (possibly) be easier to read
- if you decide you need to port the code you may have an easier time (though C++11 is standard, so somewhere down the line all compilers will implement it)

Comment: Hi, regarding "your code will not have any wrapper overhead (however small it may be)" so you're saying in theory the C++11 classes will be more efficient?

Comment: @user997112 AFAIK boost is using c++11 threads if possible, so there must be some overhead for wrapping around them.

Comment: @Dariusz no, it's not, these are 2 completely distinct products.