# Best practice: should I use std::thread, Boost, or native calls?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, stdthread

Whats best practice to use: std::thread, native calls, or some library? Is std::thread a 'don't-actually-use-this' convenience, or should it be used whenever threading is needed? Before c++11 came around, it looked like some threading library was best for portability, but now that std::thread is a thing...

What should be used - in terms of industry-standard - in major projects now?

Comment: Use the one that best suits your use case / company practice. The idiomatic way should be the `std::thread`.

Comment: I find the notion of the ISO C++ committee intentionally adding a support type you better not use... odd.

Comment: A few years later with a lot more experience: I use std::thread now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb:

- If something has been in the standard library for > X years, use it unless you know it won't fit your needs.
- If something has been in the standard library for <= X years, and you're writing non-critical code: Same as before - use it.
- Otherwise:

  - Look for how it got into the standard library (often: Boost);
  - Snoop around for discussions mentioning both of them, posts by authors, etc.;
  - Map feature set / design decision differences;
  - if you still don't have enough information to make a decision, ask here.

In your case, see:

[C++ 11 Thread vs Boost Thread is there any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773749/c-11-thread-vs-boost-thread-is-there-any-difference)

where you'll notice Boost threads have some features not in the standard. If you need those, use the Boost threads, otherwise use `std::thread`.

Comment: How do you choose X?

Comment: @ChrisHunt: I pray to a little effigy of Bjarne Stroustrup? Seriously, I don't know. Definitely X > 3, so it needs to be in there for more than one cycle of the standard.

Comment: Yes, the "next standard" is a good criterion. If the next standard has heavily revised the feature, it may be best to avoid it, eg not-so-smart_ptr.

Answer (score -2):

There is no one answer to rule them all.

TL;DR It depends

If you want **best performance**(maybe one of the reasons you are using c++) use **native calls**. You have full control and no overhead from wrapper classes and checks.

If you need **portability** and **support of c++11** is present the implementation in **std is a good choice**. Most of the time this option would be the easiest to start with and have most resources available.

Currently the **boost** duplicates the features of the standard. But it is still viable option if a **compiler does not support c++11**. In the latest few revisions same boost features are copied directly in the standard.(smart pointers for example)

Comment: `std::thread` in particular is an *extremely* thin wrapper (read: one-liner) over Linux `pthread_create` or Windows `_beginthreadex`. I sincerely doubt that Kurtoid can do any better.